# Why does this print "none" on line 3

Tags: python

Why does this print none on line 3, what can I do instead? I'm still trying to learn so please keep it simple.

```
def base():
   print("----|")
   print("|"), head()
   print("|")
   print("|")
   print("|")
   print("==========")
def head():
    print(" ( ) ")
def arms():
    print(" /|\ ")
def body():
    print("  |  ")
def legs():
    print(" / \ ")


base()
```

Comment: Because the `head` function returns `None`.

Comment: Doesn't return that when run with Python3

Comment: Thank you, How can I make head function only return the print statement?

Comment: `return " ( ) "`

Comment: print is a statement in python 2 and a function on python 3. So head may be returning the return value of print in Python 3?

Comment: @geckos: `head` is returning `None`, like all Python functions without an explicit `return` value. `print` also returns `None`, but that's unrelated to `head`'s return (because `head` didn't do `return print(...)`). Python doesn't make the `return` value use the value of the last expression by default; if you don't explicitly `return` something, you return `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Python 2. Therefore, `print` is statement.
The code is written for Python3, were `print()` is a function.
Add:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

as the first line of your code to make it work.
Otherwise all the `()` have no effect and line:

```
print("|"), head()
```

means:

```
print "|", head()
```

and it prints the return value of `head()`.

Comment: He's going to have issues with linebreaks too, but I guess it'll end up in an other question.